# Will std::make_unique<alignas(32) std::byte[]> allocate aligned memory?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, memory-alignment

I'm wondering if I can replace code like

```c++
std::unique_ptr<std::byte[]> p { new (std::align_val_t{32}) std::byte[size]{} };
```

with

```c++
auto p = std::make_unique<alignas(32) std::byte[]>(size);
```

Comment: It should not, the attribute will be ignored in template specialization

Comment: Stumbled upon this, the first syntax has a bug: `usual deallocation function 'void operator delete(void *,std::align_val_t) noexcept' would be chosen as placement deallocation function.`, I have not yet found an elegant way to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first problem is that there is no such type as `alignas(32) std::byte[]`. It is not a valid *type-id*. You can see the grammar for *type-id* [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.name#nt:type-id).

To make `alignas(32)` apply to `std::byte[]`, you would have to put it at the end: `std::byte[] alignas(32)`. This is grammatically correct, but it has no effect. In other words, `std::byte[] alignas(32)` is the same type as `std::byte[]`. As such,

```
std::make_unique<std::byte[] alignas(32)>
```

is the same as

```
std::make_unique<std::byte[]>
```

It will not align the allocated memory to a 32-byte boundary.

This is a common source of confusion, so I will elaborate a bit. Consider the following:

```
alignas(16) char c;
```

The variable (or non-static data member) `c` will be aligned to a 16-byte boundary. But why?

It is natural to think that `alignas(16) char` is the type of `c`, and that since this type has an alignment of 16, the variable has an alignment of 16. But it's not so. `alignas(16)` should be thought of as being more like `extern` or `inline`. It applies to the variable, not the type. The type of `c` is `char`, and the alignment of `c` is 16.

Alignment is just not part of the type system (though, of course, every complete type *has* an alignment).